# Will changing the energy density of the vacuum alter its permitivity or permeability?

Tags: electromagnetism, quantum-electrodynamics, refraction, vacuum, casimir-effect

If one uses lasers or a variation of the Casimir effect to change the energy density of a region of free space, will this also change the permeability and the permittivity of this same region? Why or why not?